# How to force locale within an Android app

Tags: android, localization

I am developing an android app and the task is to support three languages. In the first screen the user selects language and rest of the app should appear in selected language.

I can use localization feature such as creating a default `res/values/string.xml` and language specific files `res/values-fr/strings.xml`. When the app is opened on a device with `FR` locale all strings appear translated.

Question: *How do I force a locale on button click so that the next activity should use `res/values-fr/strings.xml`*

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try:

```
public class SigmaMiddleEastApplication extends PPGApplication {

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        newConfig.locale = Locale.ENGLISH;
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        Locale.setDefault(newConfig.locale);
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(newConfig, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
}
```

or take a look at the following attribute:

```
android:configChanges="locale"
```

Comment: Where do you use this ? Should you do it in every activity ?

Comment: I think you should be doing this only once. But I doubt this will work on devices > 4.2 since google removed this API to only for OEMs